# Pandas flatting a dataframe by two different ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe two different ID's

```
   global_duns   name  vendor_duns
0      9581091  Name1     53506312
1      9581091  Name2    961273620
2     79735371  Name3     53506312
3     79735371  Name4     79735371
4     79735371  Name5    135962137
```

You can see that the the vendor ID 53506312 is associated across two globals duns.

I would like to flatten it down to one row.

```
global1  global2   vendor1  vendor2    vendor3
9581091  79735371  53506312 961273620  135962137
```

This is just one hypothetical, a company could have x number of globals and y number of vendors.

Here is the code to create the dataframe.

```
global_duns = [9581091, 9581091, 79735371, 79735371, 79735371]
duns = [53506312, 961273620, 53506312, 79735371, 135962137]
names = ['Name1',
        'Name2',
        'Name3',
        'Name4',
        'Name5']

df = pd.DataFrame({'global_duns': global_duns, 'vendor_duns': duns, 'name': names})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using stack() and Transpose

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.drop('name', axis = 1).stack().drop_duplicates()).T
df1.columns = df1.columns.tolist()
```

This gives

```
    (0, global_duns)    (0, vendor_duns)    (1, vendor_duns)    (2, global_duns)    (4, vendor_duns)
0   9581091     53506312        961273620       79735371        135962137
```

The current tuple gives the exact combination of both the levels of the multiindex dataframe. If you wish to rename

```
df1.columns = ['global1', 'vendor1', 'vendor2', 'global2', 'vendor3']
```

You will get

```
    global1   vendor1   vendor2     global2     vendor3
0   9581091   53506312  961273620   79735371    135962137
```